# Using datatable as datasource in micrsosoft report viewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, reportviewer

Is it possible to use datatables as datasource for reportviewer component? Can you provide refference or simple steps how to do that?

And one important thing: i'm using reportviewer for webforms (ASP.net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
this.reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear(); 
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
dt = this.inputValuesTableAdapter.GetData();     

Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource rprtDTSource = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource(dt.TableName, dt); 

this.reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rprtDTSource); 
this.reportViewer.RefreshReport();
```

Hope it helps

Comment: And is it possible to specify that data source in design time?

Comment: @seeker what do you mean ? Give an example

Comment: there is design master for reports. There i placed some text and table(reportviewer control) to represent my datatable. how can i set specific table in report file(.rdlc) to be bound to datatable?

Comment: Thanks, that's right direction, but still i cannot figure out how to add data source in design master. I can only do this during runtime.