# Filling reportviewer with datatable in WinForms applications

Tags: c#, reportviewer

I tried many solution but I always get an empty `reportviewer` and I am sure that my datatable is not empty.

Here is my code:

```
private void Alarm_Filter_Submit_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Report_Title_Label.Text = "Event Logs Report";
    int siteId = FormAdminDAO.GetSiteId(customerId, siteName);
    DataTable alarmDetailsTable = 
        FormAdminDAO.GetEventLogsReport(siteId, batteryIdString, batteryTypeString, startDate, endDate);

    CurrentReportResultsTable = alarmDetailsTable;
    alarmDetailsTable.TableName = "Table1";

    reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
    ReportDataSource source = new ReportDataSource("Table1", alarmDetailsTable);
    reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
    reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(source);

    reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
    //Report_Table_Grid.DataSource = alarmDetailsTable;

    Report_Table_Panel.Visible = true;
    Alarm_Report_Filter_Panel.Visible = false;
}
```

I know the DataTable is being retrieved properly as the dataGridView works but when I tried to fill reportviewer with my DataTable, I got this message displayed on the reportviewer: "The source of the report definition has not been specified."

I tried multipe solutions like [Using datatable as datasource in micrsosoft report viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11672237/using-datatable-as-datasource-in-micrsosoft-report-viewer), [Datatable as datasource in ReportViewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725634/datatable-as-datasource-in-reportviewer), [How to bind datatable to reportviewer runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778844/how-to-bind-datatable-to-reportviewer-runtime), [How can I load datatable as ReportDataSource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004307/how-can-i-load-datatable-as-reportdatasource) but unfortunately they do not seem to work for my project.

Please, tell me how can I use my `DataTable` correctly to fill the `reportviewer` and to not get an empty `ReportViewer`.

Comment: Please tell what you've tried, show code etc. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I updated my post as you requested , could you help me please ?

Comment: I don't know exactly what makes the difference to your approache ... but I use a BindingSource in my ReportViewer and a wrap the DataTable with a DataView ...